# Android Relative Layout, Image on Full Height

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Hello everybody I have following layout as ITEM LIST. The problem is that red view image (@+id/image) isn`t filling it`s parent. Can somebody help me ?

What i want to have is four lines with buttons and image that is stretched on right border
T - text
I - image
B - button
- - horizontal Divider

```
T         B  I
T T          I
____________ I
T         T  I



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dummy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tw_ticket_background"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:longClickable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/red" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/infoIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text2"
        android:text="text3"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/horizontalRule"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/secondLine"
    android:background="#000000" 
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalRule" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text4"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="text5"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you want to do..your question is not clear...

Comment: try this   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

Comment: What i want to have is four lines with texts, button and image that is stretched on right border exactly as shown on top of this post

Comment: can you post image of this layuot..so it will be more clear...

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6816743/image.png please note that the right red is not a border but needs to be an image

Comment: ok..so righ tnow..it is getting like this??

Comment: no it is not, i don`t know if it is even possible

Comment: how you want to show ur layout,do you have any example..that like this..i want to show or display my iamge

Comment: you have example how i want it above - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6816743/image.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:background="@drawable/red" />
```